# Compile Old Asp.NET WebForm project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to open a old asp.net webform project in Visual Studio 2022. This project was developed with Visual Studio .NET 7.1 and uses .NET v2.
When i opened the project i changed target framework to .NET v2.

But i still can't compile the project.

I read about this error in several forum posts, where they mentioned that it could be references issue. But for example I didn't find the reference folder in solution explorer, and i don't know how many references were used in project. How can i find this information?

When i try to compile appear the error:

"Could not load type "supervisorio.Global""

Look my Global.asasx file:

```
<%@ Application CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="supervisorio.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

Here part of my Global.asax.cs file:

```
namespace supervisorio 
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Global.
/// </summary>
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    // Indica o caminho do diretório temporário
    private static string strDirTemporario = "";

    private clsComunicacaoADS commADS = null;

    public Global()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        commADS = new clsComunicacaoADS();
    }
}
```

And I think this error is the cause of the other errors, which mention not recognizing classes:

[image]

The types not recognized in image above are declared in 'clsEstruturas.cs'.

I try to make changes in Global.asax

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you opening this as a asp.net web site (file->open web site), or was/is this project a asp.net web site "application" (and thus has a sln (project) file?

Comment: I open a sln file.

Comment: Right, but it possbile that the project was never intended to be a "project". If you by accident open the project (using file->open project), then you wind up with a project as a web project. I would try opening the project using file->open web site. This might solve the references issue(s). It rather hard to debug and set your references on a SO post - we can't try 50 things in say the next 5 minutes to resolve this. And trying 50 things only takes about 5-10 minutes. This looks like your references are messed up, and you could expand the references in the project explore and see any missing

Comment: That's the problem, the reference folder doesn't exist when i open the project. It looks like the csproj file is not making any difference, would it be possible to unlink it and relink it then?

Comment: You can as a general rule can even delete the csproj file or even the .sln file IF THE PROJECT WAS a web site, and not a web site application. Again, are you using file->open web site, or you going file->open project and opening the csprj or sln file? A MASSIVE difference here!!! If you NOT using what is called a "asp.net web site application", and in fact are using a "asp.net web site", then no prj or sln file is required. To setup references, you can right click on the bin folder and choose add reference (you don't have a manage reference page (quite much the WHOLE point here!!!).

Comment: I try open my project with 2 methods, and the build returns me the same errors.

Comment: .NET v2? is this referring to .NET Framework 2.0? if yes, you might need to install it at [windows] > [control panel] > [uninstall or change program] > turn windows feature on or off > .net framework 3.5 (include 2.0 and 3.0)